# Writing data to a running executable file

Tags: assembly, process, reverse-engineering, masm32

I'm trying to run a process, wait for it to finish, open the executable file, and write something to it. So i created a small "loader" which does exactly that.
This is my code:

```
;Run the executable
INVOKE GetStartupInfo,OFFSET startInfo 
INVOKE CreateProcess, ADDR SomeExecutableFile, \
    NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, \ 
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,  NULL,NULL, \
    OFFSET startInfo, OFFSET processInfo 
INVOKE CloseHandle, processInfo.hThread    

;Wait for it to finish & Close handle
INVOKE WaitForSingleObjectEx, processInfo.hProcess,   INFINITE,  FALSE
INVOKE CloseHandle, processInfo.hProcess

;Try to open the same exe file  which just finished executing.
INVOKE CreateFile,  OFFSET SomeExecutableFile,GENERIC_WRITE \
    ,0, 0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL

MOV hFile, EAX

.IF hFile== INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    INVOKE MessageBox,NULL, OFFSET Problem, OFFSET Problem, MB_ICONWARNING
.ELSE
    INVOKE WriteFile, hFile, Buffer, 5, OFFSET BytesWritten , NULL
    INVOKE CloseHandle,hFile
.ENDIF

INVOKE ExitProcess,0
```

As you can see, 'SomeExecutable' file is being ran. After it stops executing it is opened with CreateFile.
Create file fails, and i get an INVALID_HANDLE...., Last error- 0x20 - ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

Why does this happen?

Thoughts & Notes:
1) Creating another process from the "loader" which opens the executable file(After waiting for it to finish executing) and write to it - it works.
2) It seems like the process is still open, i.e the file is still mapped which explains the error, but i don't understand why would it be mapped.
3) Debugging with Olly & ProcessExplorer i saw that indeed Olly has a handle of this file open even after the process has terminated, and all handles were closed - I don't understand why, and how the hell can i close it :)

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

1- Try to use:

```
invoke CreateProcess, ADDR Process, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, ADDR startInfo, ADDR processInfo
```

CREATE_SUSPENDED should do the trick

2- Do you need to modify the file itself? Loaders usually are used to modify programs in memory. I wrote a loader some time ago with **WriteProcessMemory**:

```
.586 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 

include D:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
include D:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
include D:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib D:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib D:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

.data 
  Process byte "prog.exe",0 
  Error byte "Error:",0 
  ErrorMessage byte "Process not loaded",0 
  ReplaceBy byte 0Fh,82h
  ReplaceSize dword 2 
  AddressToPatch dword 01003B7Ch 
  Startup STARTUPINFO <> 
  processinfo PROCESS_INFORMATION <> 

.data? 
  byteswritten dword ?

.code 
  start: 
    invoke CreateProcess, ADDR Process, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, ADDR Startup, ADDR processinfo 
    cmp eax, 0 
    jne ProcessCreated 
    push 0 
    push offset Error 
    push offset ErrorMessage 
    push 0 
    call MessageBox 
    push 0 
    call ExitProcess 

    ProcessCreated: 
        invoke WriteProcessMemory, processinfo.hProcess, AddressToPatch, ADDR ReplaceBy, ReplaceSize, byteswritten 
        invoke ResumeThread, processinfo.hThread 
    push 0 
    call ExitProcess 
  end start
```